# Semantic Role no longer tagging adjectives as Modifiers

Tags: allennlp

Last October (2020) we ran some data through the Semantic Role function. With the sentence "John would like a comprehensive map of Ohio." the word comprehensive was tagged as a modifier. Now, however, it seems like none of the adjectives in our data get tagged as modifiers.
[image: SR Results on May 6th 2021]
https://demo.allennlp.org/semantic-role-labeling/s/john-would-like-a-ohio/F8U2O6P5I3

What's changed? Will the previous SemRole capability be restored? Do we have to resort to Dependency Parsing?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to debug models with just one example, but I do agree that that output looks weird. I've tried a few different combinations of old AllenNLP releases and old models, but I can't replicate the results you mentioned.

In general though, you shouldn't rely on the demos for consistent results. Instead, you can use the tool itself and use whatever version you like to make sure your system is consistent. E.g. on the command line:

```
pip install allennlp==2.1.0 allennlp-models==2.1.0

echo '{"sentence": "Did Uriah honestly think he could beat the game in under three hours?."}' | \
    allennlp predict https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/structured-prediction-srl-bert.2020.12.15.tar.gz -
```